# Searching for a particular term on Google under a specific website domain

Tags: google-search

I want to search on Google for some terms but the requirements are that the website's domain name must be `.edu`. How do I set up my search to filter out all those websites and domains that do not end in **.edu**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `site:` operator allows you to restrict results to a domain.  It may be applied to a top-level domain (ex. `.com`, `.org`), second-level domain (ex. `google.com`), or any higher-level domain (ex. `gaming.stackexchange.com`).  There must not be a space between the colon in `site:` and the start of the domain.

To limit search results to the `.edu` top-level domain, add the `site:.edu` term to the query.

For more information about the `site:` and other advanced operators, see http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136861.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting to note that space before.edu matters.